# if httpRequest body can be modified?

Tags: java, spring-boot, httprequest, netflix-zuul, consul

I am building an gateway project in java because there are lots of internal project which has different business param rules I want to unify the param rule to the external user.

I want to use the zuul to route the request because our company's services are mostly built with spring boot and communicating through Consul. But it seems that the request body seems can not be modified. I must relaunch an request to change the body.

Is there any solution to help me fix this problem?

Comment: So before you send the xmlhttprequest, but after you've set the body, you want to change the body?

Comment: yes,but Content-Type is json

Comment: I think that the thing to do here is to only start building the request once you're certain of what is going to be.